# Can't start multiprocessing Pool in dask task

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cluster-computing, dask, distributed-computing

I am trying to compute a dask custom graph in a remote cluster using the Client.get method, but I have been running into the following error: `AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children`

I realized that one of the underlying methods in the dask graph uses a process pool, which causes this error to be raised, since dask also tries to use a process pool himself. So, the way I sort of fixed this was by using a LocalCluster and passing the argument `processes=False`. However, the unfortunate thing is that dask won't let me pass the `process=False` if I am using a Client attached to a remote cluster, and also initializing the remote workers with the --nprocs=1 argument won't work as well.

All in all, I am able to run the graph, but it is quite frustrating that I can't use multiprocessing capabilities when computing the dask graph, and can't use remote clusters. Any ideas on how to implement one (or maybe both) of these requirements?

Thanks in advance

### Code Sample

This is what I intended to do, but got the AssertionError to be thrown:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client(<some-remote-ip-address-here>)

def foo():
    pool = Pool()  # the exception is raised here, on the Pool object initialization
    ... does something here ...
    returns True

graph = {'result': foo}

client.get(graph, 'result')
```

This is how I "fixed" it, by removing the multiprocessing capabilities, and setting a local cluster:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client(processes=False)  # this yields a LocalCluster that doesn't have multiprocessing capabilities (doc is very brief and not very helpful: http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/api.html#distributed.LocalCluster)

def foo():
    pool = Pool()  # no exception is raised
    ... does something here ...
    returns True

graph = {'result': foo}

client.get(graph, 'result')
```

Comment: can would create a minimum working example of this for a local pool? if not, can you at least show the function calls that generate this error and the full traceback?

Comment: Just provided a code sample to better illustrate the problem @PaulH

Comment: why are you trying to mix dask with multiprocessing? but yes - the short answer is don't/you can't do this

Comment: Ok, and how can I set a remote cluster that doesn't use multiprocessing?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are after, but for orchestration (with mpi, if needed) this might be useful https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0):

Like @Michael Delgado told himself, there is no way to do such thing. The only workaround I found was using a LocalCluster passing `processes=False` or launching a remote worker passing the `--no-nanny` argument. This shall make the code above work, but without multiprocessing capabilities.